# Where can I find the files from Ghidra symbol tree?

Tags: disassembly, windows, ghidra

I have decompiled a `.dll` file with Ghidra. At the left, I see the symbol tree. In the symbol tree, there is a tab `imports`. This tab contains external `.dll` files. Where can I find the location of these files on my Windows laptop?